# Getting exeception while executing my android app on emulator. (But its working fine on phone)

Tags: java, android

Getting this exception while executing on emulator.

[image]

I think this is related to some memory issue.
Because its working fine when am trying it on my phone.

Anyone help me to find the real reason for this problem?

Galleryview.java

```
package example.hitwallhd;

import example.hitwallhd.ImageDownloader;
import example.hitwallhd.ImageDownloader.ImageLoaderListener;
import example.hitwallhd.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

public class Galleryview extends Activity {

    private ProgressBar pb;
    private Button save,bnxt,bprv;
    private ImageView img;
    private static Bitmap bmp;
    private TextView percent;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private ImageDownloader mDownloader;
    TextView t1,t2;

    String num,cate,addrs,urladdrs,pviews,pdown,sele;
    int savecount=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_galleryview);
        save.setEnabled(false);
        initViews();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            num = extras.getString("num");
            cate = extras.getString("category");
            sele = extras.getString("sele");
            addrs= extras.getString("picno");
            t1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            t2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            //t1.setText(pviews);
            //t2.setText(pdown);
            urladdrs="http://someaddrs.com/wallpapers/"+cate+"/"+addrs;

                /*--- instantiate our downloader passing it required components ---*/
                mDownloader = new ImageDownloader(urladdrs, pb, save, img, percent, Galleryview.this, bmp, new ImageLoaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageDownloaded(Bitmap bmp) {
                        Galleryview.bmp = bmp;
             /*--- here we assign the value of bmp field in our Loader class 
                       * to the bmp field of the current class ---*/    
                    }
                    });

                /*--- we need to call execute() since nothing will happen otherwise ---*/
                mDownloader.execute();
                save.setEnabled(true);

    }

    private void initViews() {


        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        //bnxt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext);
        //bprv=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bprev);
        /*--- we are using 'this' because our class implements the OnClickListener ---*/
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbDownload);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        percent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        percent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    public void onclick_next(View v)
    {
        bprv.setEnabled(true);
        GetData obj = new GetData();

        int nxt=Integer.parseInt(num)+1;
        num=String.valueOf(nxt);

        String urls="http://someaddrs.com/wallpapers/newlist.php?cate="+cate+"&no="+num+"&prev=0";
        obj.execute(urls);

    }

    public void onclick_prev(View v)
    {
        bnxt.setEnabled(true);
        GetData obj = new GetData();

        int nxt=Integer.parseInt(num)-1;
        num=String.valueOf(nxt);

        String urls="http://someaddrs.com/wallpapers/newlist.php?cate="+cate+"&no="+num+"&prev=1";
        obj.execute(urls);

    }

    public void onclick_save(View v)
    {
        saveImageToSD();
        String cnum;
        if(urladdrs.equals("nexterror"))
        {
            int nxt=Integer.parseInt(num)-1;
            cnum=String.valueOf(nxt);
        }
        else if(urladdrs.equals("preverror"))
        {
            int nxt=Integer.parseInt(num)+1;
            cnum=String.valueOf(nxt);
        }
        else
            cnum=num;
        savecount=1;
        GetData obj = new GetData();
        String urls="http://someaddrs.com/wallpapers/downloadcount.php?no="+cnum;
        obj.execute(urls);
    }

    private void saveImageToSD() {

        /*--- this method will save your downloaded image to SD card ---*/

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        /*--- you can select your preferred CompressFormat and quality. 
         * I'm going to use JPEG and 100% quality ---*/
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        /*--- create a new file on SD card ---*/
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + num+"Image.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*--- create a new FileOutputStream and write bytes to file ---*/
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent pview = new Intent(Galleryview.this,HitWall.class);
        startActivity(pview);

    }

    public void looperfn()
    {
        t1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t1.setText(pviews);
        t2.setText(pdown);
        if(urladdrs.equals("nexterror"))
        {
            int nxt=Integer.parseInt(num)-1;
            num=String.valueOf(nxt);
            bnxt.setEnabled(false);

        }
        else if(urladdrs.equals("preverror"))
        {
            int nxt=Integer.parseInt(num)+1;
            num=String.valueOf(nxt);
            bprv.setEnabled(false);

        }
        else
        {
            //t1.setText(urladdrs);
        urladdrs="http://someaddrs.com/wallpapers/"+cate+"/"+urladdrs;

        mDownloader = new ImageDownloader(urladdrs, pb, save, img, percent, Galleryview.this, bmp, new ImageLoaderListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageDownloaded(Bitmap bmp) {
                Galleryview.bmp = bmp;
     /*--- here we assign the value of bmp field in our Loader class 
               * to the bmp field of the current class ---*/    
            }
            });

        /*--- we need to call execute() since nothing will happen otherwise ---*/
        mDownloader.execute();
        }
    }

    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            BufferedReader reader =null;
            String data =null;

            try{

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI uri=new URI(params[0]);

                HttpGet get =new HttpGet(uri);

                HttpResponse response= client.execute(get);

                InputStream stream=response.getEntity().getContent();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";


                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                data = buffer.toString();

                if(data.equals("preverror")||data.equals("nexterror"))
                {
                    return data;
                }
                else
                {
                    pviews=data.substring(data.indexOf("|")+1,data.indexOf(":"));
                    pviews=" Views : "+pviews;
                    pdown=data.substring(data.indexOf(":")+1, data.length());
                    pdown="      Downloads : "+pdown;
                    data=data.substring(0, data.indexOf("|"));
                    return data;
                }

                //data=data.substring(0, data.indexOf("|"));
                //t1.setText(data);

            }
            catch(URISyntaxException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException f){
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException g){
                g.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if(reader!=null){
                    try{
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            urladdrs=result;
            if(savecount==0)
            {
             looperfn();
            }
            else
                savecount=0;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Paste the logcat and also the GalleryView's Activity code

Comment: Please copy/paste the text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

This type of issue is arrived due to memory leakage.
the main problem is that there is `Java.lang.NullPointerException` and this type of exception arrives when there is low virtual memory.
As there is low virtual memory in emulator so it is getting the error and the phone has the sufficient virtual memory to display and load the image in the memory.

Comment: whenever you want to load the image just create a scaled bitmap image of existing image and load it. it removes the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an exception in `Galleryview.java` at line 57. Please provide the peace of code around line 57 or the whole `Galleryview.java`.

Comment: mentioned that in question.

Comment: @jomin: You didn't see the original question. There was no source code. The author edited the question and added the source code.